# Marketing Cloud logs and error logs

Tags: marketing-cloud

are you aware of any logging or administrative tools for the Marketing Cloud? I feel like the admin user should be able to access more information than the ones that are normally available from the UI. Especially in case of errors and exceptions. I am just wondering if Salesforce Professional Services do have access to advanced consoles that maybe clients could just ask to be enabled by the help desk.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error log access used to exist for certain SFMC Partners.  You're stuck getting any run-time error details from SFMC Support now.

In my opinion, SF could save themselves a lot of support money by providing tools for their customers to debug their own configurations.  Rolling the old ExactTarget Support into the Salesforce infrastructure was a huge step backwards and is a constant frustration for those of us supporting multiple large/complex SFMC clients.

Answer (score 0):

The [latest release](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/september_2016_release/#platform) has enhanced their error logging access to Automation Studio programs.

Comment: Please add some detail from the link to explain why it answers the question.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that.  It's a step in the right direction, but it's sadly not enough.  In working with it, it doesn't appear to [cover all of the T-SQL runtime errors that can occur in Query Activities](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/136180/5202).  Plus, as far as I can tell, it's limited to Query Activities.

Comment: The link in the answer is dead.