# Query Activity failing on calculated field

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Can someone see my error? I'm trying add these calculated fields into a Text(20) column of a Data Extension.

```
ROUND(CAST(C.USD_SALE_PRICE AS INT)/CAST(C.USD_RETAIL_PRICE AS INT)*100,0) AS PRICE_DIFFERENCE_PERCENTILE

ROUND(CAST(C.USD_RETAIL_PRICE AS INT)-CAST(C.USD_SALE_PRICE AS INT),0) AS PRICE_DIFFERENCE_ABSOLUTE
```

Comment: What about the Primary Key(s) of your Data Extension?

Comment: See this answer for some [common runtime errors](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/136180/5202)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a Data Type conversion error. :-(

```
ROUND(CAST(C.USD_SALE_PRICE AS DECIMAL)/CAST(C.USD_RETAIL_PRICE AS DECIMAL)*100,0) AS PRICE_DIFFERENCE_PERCENTILE

ROUND(CAST(C.USD_RETAIL_PRICE AS DECIMAL)-CAST(C.USD_SALE_PRICE AS DECIMAL),0) AS PRICE_DIFFERENCE_ABSOLUTE
```

Comment: Please turn this into a proper answer where you show how you now do the field conversion, thanks.