# Query issue - Automation failed due to system error

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, sql

I have a sql-query where i do not know my mistake therefore it would be nice if you could help.

```
SELECT
SUM(b.HardBounceCount) AS HardBounceCount,
SUM(b.SoftBounceCount) AS SoftBounceCount, 
SUM(b.BlockBounceCount) AS BlockBounceCount,
SUM(b.UnknownBounceCount) AS UnknownBounceCount, 
SUM(b.TechnicalBounceCount) AS TechnicalBounceCount,
SUM(b.BounceCount) AS BounceCount,
SUM(b.SendCount) AS SendCount,
b.Domain AS Domain
FROM [SubscriberBounces] b
GROUP BY b.Domain
```

My source data extension looks like (other values than 0 and 1 possible):[image]

My target data extension looks like:
[image]

Do you have any advice how i can correct my query? Additionally can i insert BouncePercent directly when i add an additional line like

`cast(round((SUM(b.BounceCount)*100.0)/SUM(b.SendCount),2) as numeric(5,2)) as BouncePercent,`

Furthermore i have seen that datakid / Gortonington / adam spriggs have been dumping the error results in data extensions (but i could not find any of these posts, if you can share how i can dump the sql error in a data extension it would be nice too)

Errors:
First - Activity View Instant Error:
[image]
Inside Automation when you try to run once:
[image]
Inside Automation Studio Picture 2:
[image]

First try to solve it without success:

```
SELECT
SUM(b.HardBounceCount) AS HardBounceCount,
SUM(b.SoftBounceCount) AS SoftBounceCount, 
SUM(b.BlockBounceCount) AS BlockBounceCount,
SUM(b.UnknownBounceCount) AS UnknownBounceCount, 
SUM(b.TechnicalBounceCount) AS TechnicalBounceCount,
SUM(b.BounceCount) AS BounceCount,
SUM(b.SendCount) AS SendCount,
cast(round((SUM(b.BounceCount)*100.0)/SUM(b.SendCount),2) as numeric(5,2)) as BouncePercent,
LEFT(b.Domain,128) AS Domain
FROM [SubscriberBounces_LastMonth] b
GROUP BY b.Domain
```

Comment: You can see some errors if you run your Query Activity in an Automation.

Comment: When you say it's crashing, what exactly do you mean?  The syntax is valid -- even with the `BouncePercent` column included.

Comment: Why is `BouncePercent` a string in your target DE?

Comment: Because of this post https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_find_top_bounces_for_a_job_ref.htm&type=5 my BouncePercent is text.

Comment: Should be Decimal (18,2), IMO.

Comment: Yeah you are right it should be decimal but i believe Decimal(5,2) just did text because of the documentation post.

Comment: It's likely a truncation or datatype mismatch.  Query errors can only be one of [four](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/136180/5202) things.

Comment: Checking it out and implementing some left function to Domain, thats the only field which can be over 128 (doubting it though).

Comment: Domain has to be filled because its a group by of a different dataextension => Therefore it cannot be the Primary Key Violation and not the nullable reason. Inserting value to long: i restricted the only value which could have been to long by left 128. Query to Long failure after 1second seems very very odd.

Answer (score 2):

I set this up in my local SQL Server Management Studio with some test data and got it to run fine:

```
SELECT
SUM(b.HardBounceCount) AS HardBounceCount,
SUM(b.SoftBounceCount) AS SoftBounceCount, 
SUM(b.BlockBounceCount) AS BlockBounceCount,
SUM(b.UnknownBounceCount) AS UnknownBounceCount, 
SUM(b.TechnicalBounceCount) AS TechnicalBounceCount,
SUM(b.BounceCount) AS BounceCount,
cast(round((SUM(b.BounceCount)*100.0)/SUM(b.SendCount),2) as numeric(5,2)) as BouncePercent,
SUM(b.SendCount) AS SendCount,
b.Domain AS Domain
FROM [dbo].[subscriberBounces] b
GROUP BY b.Domain
```

[image: query results]

Comment: Do you generally develop your queries on a local development system to test and analyse your queries? If so which setup do you use for it? Do you use function like `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for it?

Comment: Sometimes.  It depends on the complexity of the query or queries involved.  I do frequently use SQL Server Management Studio for basic query validation.  That kind of syntax validation isn't dependent on any schema.