# SQL Won't Populate Salesforce Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I am trying to dump data from a Salesforce object into a Salesforce Data Extension. I am not getting an errors but the data refuses to populate. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong! I have tried Append, Update, and Overwrite as well.

I am in our parent account so I don't think I need the Ent. prefix. Here is the SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber, PersonEmail, Phone, Name, Status__pc, 
Agent_Type__c 
FROM Account_Salesforce
WHERE Status__pc = 'Active'
AND Agent_Type__c = 'Concierge'
```

And here is the set-up for the target data extension:

[image]

Like I stated I am getting no run-time errors and the query seems super basic. I have no idea why it won't populate!

Comment: Anything showing in the Activity Log for the Query?

Comment: Nope, I keep running it and I am getting nothing

Comment: Does it populate with the where-clause removed?  And how many rows are in Account_Salesforce and has it finished syncing?

Comment: Let me test one second

Comment: No population when the where-clause is removed

Comment: Wait just got this error when running it "Automation failed due to system error."

Comment: It's one of these 4 things then: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/136180/5202

Comment: might be a primary key violation. E.g. You have duplicate 'Account Numbers' in your SF DE and with `Distinct` It will read them as a different record, instead of an update since distinct uses all listed in select as the 'unique keys'

Comment: Try to make all your fields Nullable and then run. Or there could be some data truncation happening

Comment: Running through the options above, I will keep you all updated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with data truncation, the issue was one rouge row that had more than the allotted characters!