# SFMC: SQL Query on Dataview objects to calculate Journey's sends, opens, and clicks

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, data-views

I want to calculate the sends, opens, and clicks of all journeys. Expecting the records in Date Extension consists of records in the following sequence:

```
JourneyActivityObjectID
VersionID
ActivityName
ActivityType
JourneyName
VersionNumber
EmailName
Sends
Opens
Clicks
```

What's wrong with this query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
    ,ja.VersionID
    ,ja.ActivityName
    ,ja.ActivityType
    ,j.JourneyName
    ,j.VersionNumber
    ,jb.EmailName
    ,s.Sends
    ,o.Opens
    ,c.Clicks
FROM [_JourneyActivity] ja
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
         VersionID
        ,JourneyName
        ,VersionNumber
    FROM [_Journey]
) j ON j.VersionID = ja.VersionID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
        ,EmailName
    FROM [_Job]
) jb ON jb.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
         TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
        ,Count(*) AS Sends
    FROM [_Sent]
    GROUP BY TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
) s ON s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
        ,Count(*) AS Opens
    FROM [_Open]
    GROUP BY TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
) o ON o.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
        ,Count(*) AS Clicks
    FROM [_Click]
    GROUP BY TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
) c ON c.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you run it in Automation Studio?

Comment: Chaining a bunch of JOINs to multiple data views is a recipe for a timeout.

Comment: Also, query failures are generally caused by one of these 4 things: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/136180/5202

Comment: Another note to add is that using DISTINCT will mark everything in the SELECT statement as Pkeys. So by placing a DISTINCT in there you are looking at 10 Pkeys, essentially negating the DISTINCT statement completely. If you want to ensure unique records only, I would recommend using the rank() function which will let you partition by your desired keys.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - thank you for the comments. No data in my DE :-(

Comment: To verify, your Query runs with no errors, but provides no data? No errors when run in Automation Studio or checking the log (Action Log) on the Query Activity?